# How to make MouseClick happen?

Tags: java

I am trying to use MouseClick to click on a certain spot and change the color of that spot but unfortunately I can't make it work. Can anyone help me with this "without giving away the code"? Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.Toolkit.*;

public class Project extends JPanel
implements KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
  char shape = 'r';
  int x=0;
  int y=0;

  boolean levels = false;

  public Project() {
    setFocusable(true);
    addKeyListener(this);
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    setSize(400,400);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Dimension d = getSize();
    g.setColor(getBackground());
    g.fillRect(0,0,d.width,d.height);
    setBackground (Color.cyan);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawString("X: " + x + " Y: " + y, 5,10);

    //Levels
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(300,165,100,50);
    g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 30));
    g.setColor(Color.cyan);
    g.drawString("Levels", 300, 200);

    if (x >= 300 && x <= 402 && y >= 165 && y <= 218 && levels) {
      g.setColor(Color.red);
    }
    //Levels
  }

  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    shape = e.getKeyChar();
    repaint();
  }

  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if (x >= 300 && x <= 402 && y >= 165 && y <= 218) {
       levels= true;
    }
    repaint();
  }

  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}

  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
     x=e.getX();
     y=e.getY();
     repaint();
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Project");
    Project dc = new Project();
    f.getContentPane().add(dc);
    f.setSize(1200,775);
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e ){
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  How doesn't it work?

Comment: So basically, you want draw with the mouse. That's ultimately what you are suggesting when you say you want to color a `spot`. I'm assuming this means a point.

Comment: I don't understand the point of your code. In the mouseClicked() method you set the "levels" variable to true, but you don't test that variable in your painting code, so I'm not sure what you expect to happen.

Comment: @peeskillet@tieTYT It supposed to change the color of the certain spot from x># and x<# and y># and y<#, when I click but nothing happens.

Comment: Just as a future note, you should put spaces between operators in your statements. It makes it a ton easier to read. I'll edit that in in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the color variable as a class member, so all members can use it.

```
public class Project .... {

    Color color = Color.RED;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        ...
        g.setColor(color);
        ...
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        color = Color.BLUE;
        repaint();
    }
}
```